# How do I avoid HeadlessException when using Smack on a server?

Tags: java, android, smack

I downloaded the Smack example code to send GCM to Android devices from a server.

When I run it on my dev machine I get a Smack debugging window.

On my server I get this:

> Exception in thread "Thread-6" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't initialize the configured debugger!
>           at org.jivesoftware.smack.Connection.initDebugger(Connection.java:797)
>           at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.initReaderAndWriter(XMPPConnection.java:731)
>           at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.initConnection(XMPPConnection.java:611)
>           at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.connectUsingConfiguration(XMPPConnection.java:596)
>           at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.connect(XMPPConnection.java:1010)
>           at se.wi.poc.brdgms.utils.Android.connect(Android.java:94)
>           at se.wi.poc.brdgms.utils.Android.push(Android.java:50)
>           at se.wi.poc.brdgms.utils.PushUtils.pushToUserInSeparateThread(PushUtils.java:30)
>           at se.wi.poc.brdgms.utils.PushUtils.access$0(PushUtils.java:26)
>           at se.wi.poc.brdgms.utils.PushUtils$1.run(PushUtils.java:20)
>   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:534)
>           at org.jivesoftware.smack.Connection.initDebugger(Connection.java:792)
>           ... 9 more
>   Caused by: java.awt.HeadlessException
>           at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:173)
>           at java.awt.Window.(Window.java:547)
>           at java.awt.Frame.(Frame.java:419)
>           at javax.swing.JFrame.(JFrame.java:218)
>           at org.jivesoftware.smack.debugger.LiteDebugger.createDebug(LiteDebugger.java:65)
>           at org.jivesoftware.smack.debugger.LiteDebugger.(LiteDebugger.java:58)
>           ... 14 more

How do I disable the Smack debug window?

Comment: You could have a look at Smack sources. It may provide you you a hint on how to avoid the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After I go

```
    myConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration(SERVER, PORT);
```

I have to go

```
    myConfig.setDebuggerEnabled(false);
```